# How to split a Torch class into several files in a Lua rock

Tags: lua, torch, luarocks

In my recently aided in the development of a Dataframe package for Torch. As the code base has quickly doubled there is a need to split the class into several sections for better organization and follow-up ([issue #8](https://github.com/AlexMili/torch-dataframe/issues/8)).

A simple test-class would be a *test.lua* file in the root folder of the test-package:

```
test = torch.class('test')
function test:__init()
  self.data = {}
end

function test:a()
  print("a")
end

function test:b()
  print("b")
end
```

Now the rockspec for this would simply be:

```
package = "torch-test"
 version = "0.1-1"
 source = {
    url = "..."
 }
 description = {
    summary = "A test class",
    detailed = [[
       Just an example
    ]],
    license = "MIT/X11",
    maintainer = "Jon Doe"
 }
 dependencies = {
    "lua ~> 5.1",
    "torch >= 7.0",
 }
 build = {
  type = 'builtin',
  modules = {
      ["test"] = 'test.lua',
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get multiple files to work for a single class it is necessary to return the class object initially created and pass it to the subsections. The above example can be put into the file structure:

```
\init.lua
\main.lua
\test-0.1-1.rockspec
\Extensions\a.lua
\Extensions\b.lua
```

The `luarocks install/make` copies the files according to 'require' syntax where each `.` signifies a directory and the `.lua` is left out, i.e. we need to change the rockspec to:

```
package = "torch-test"
 version = "0.1-1"
 source = {
    url = "..."
 }
 description = {
    summary = "A test class",
    detailed = [[
       Just an example
    ]],
    license = "MIT/X11",
    maintainer = "Jon Doe"
 }
 dependencies = {
    "lua ~> 5.1",
    "torch >= 7.0",
 }
 build = {
  type = 'builtin',
  modules = {
      ["test.init"] = 'init.lua',
      ["test.main"] = 'main.lua',
      ["test.Extensions.a"] = 'a.lua',
      ["test.Extensions.b"] = 'b.lua'
    }
  }
```

The above will thus create a *test*-folder where the packages reside together with the files and subdirectories. The class initialization now resides in the `init.lua` that returns the class object:

```
test = torch.class('test')
function test:__init()
  self.data = {}
end
return test
```

The subclass-files now need to pickup the class object that is passed using `loadfile()` (see `init.lua` file below). The `a.lua` should now look like this:

```
local params = {...}
local test = params[1]
function test:a()
  print("a")
end
```

and similar addition for the `b.lua`:

```
local params = {...}
local test = params[1]
function test:b()
  print("b")
end
```

In order to glue everything together we have the `init.lua` file. The following is probably a little over-complicated but it takes care of:

- Finding all extensions available and loading them (**Note:** requires [lua filesystem](https://keplerproject.github.io/luafilesystem/) that you should add to the rockspec and you still need to add each file into the rockspec or it won't be in the Extensions folder)
- Identifies the paths folder
- Loads the main.lua
- Works in a pure testing environment without the package installed

The code for `init.lua`:

```
require 'lfs'

local file_exists = function(name)
   local f=io.open(name,"r")
   if f~=nil then io.close(f) return true else return false end
end

-- If we're in development mode the default path should be the current
local test_path = "./?.lua"
local search_4_file = "Extensions/load_batch"
if (not file_exists(string.gsub(test_path, "?", search_4_file))) then
  -- split all paths according to ;
  for path in string.gmatch(package.path, "[^;]+;") do
    -- remove trailing ;
    path = string.sub(path, 1, string.len(path) - 1)
    if (file_exists(string.gsub(path, "?", "test/" .. search_4_file))) then
      test_path = string.gsub(path, "?", "test/?")
      break;
    end
  end
  if (test_path == nil) then
    error("Can't find package files in search path: " .. tostring(package.path))
  end
end

local main_file = string.gsub(test_path,"?", "main")
local test = assert(loadfile(main_file))()

-- Load all extensions, i.e. .lua files in Extensions directory
ext_path = string.gsub(test_path, "[^/]+$", "") .. "Extensions/"
for extension_file,_ in lfs.dir (ext_path) do
  if (string.match(extension_file, "[.]lua$")) then
    local file = ext_path .. extension_file
    assert(loadfile(file))(test)
  end
end

return test
```

I hope this helps if you run into the same problem and find the documentation a little too sparse. If you happen to know a better solution, please share.